# Conditional formatting in excel, find variable in chart

Tags: excel, charts, formatting, conditional-statements

Hi I need some help with conditional formatting in excel. 
[image]

What I want is: When I put the height of any certain individual in the "Height box" I want excel to match it to the table to the left and find the preferable weight accordingly and put the weight in the box "Preferable weight".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP() is what you are after here.

Based on your example (assuming top left col is A) put into the cell next to the preferable weight label:

`=VLOOKUP(WeightCell,$A$2:$B$12,2,0)`

where HeightCell is the cell with the value you want to look for, and the `$A$2:$B$12` part is the range of heights and weights (modify the range to suit your needs)